# Updating an Access table from a SQL server table transaction

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

My goal is to write an update trigger within a SQL server DB table. The function of this trigger is to update an Access database table with the same information that is being updated in the SQL server.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not just create a linked table in Access that points to the SQL Server table? That way you wouldn't need a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Linked Server](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/uncategorized/how-can-i-link-a-sql-server-database-to-ms-access-using-link-tables-in-ms-access/) to create communication between sql server instance and access database...

Answer (score 0):

or make use of OPENROWSET function